# Django Template inheritance (location for extends)

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to create base.html to extend it from my apps.

My structure:

ROOT(pyshop)

- polls

  - templates

    - polls

      - index.html (contains {% extends "base.html" %})
- pyshop

  - templates

    - base.html

But it can't find base.html

> Template-loader postmortem
>
> Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
>
> Using engine django:
>   django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/sz/Projects/pyshop/polls/templates/pyshop/base.html (Source does not exist)
>   django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/sz/Projects/pyshop/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/pyshop/base.html (Source does not exist)
>   django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/sz/Projects/pyshop/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/pyshop/base.html (Source does not exist)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `pyshop/pyshop/templates` directory will not be searched by the app directories loader, because it is not an app. The usual approach is to add this directory to the `DIRS` list.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'pyshop', 'templates'),]
    ...
    }
]
```

Secondly, the traceback makes it looks as if you are doing `{% extends "pyshop/base.html" %}`, not `{% extends "base.html" %}` as in your question. If you have `{% extends "base.html" %}`, then you will need to move your `base.html` template to `pyshop/pyshop/templates/pyshop/base.html`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Set DIRS resolve my issue! About {% extends "pyshop/base.html" %} i posted wrong traceback, i tried alot of different variations :)

Comment: app_dirs was true, but it doesn't help.

Comment: `'APP_DIRS': True` means that it will search the templates directories for each app in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting. However, the `pyshop/pyshop` directory (which contains `settings.py` and so on), is not usually added to `INSTALLED_APPS`, so having `'APPS': True` doesn't help. Therefore, you add the directory to `DIRS` instead.